Unmet dependency on libodbc2 blocks apt from functioning, including attempts to reinstall libodbc2
Currently running Ubuntu 23.10, I can't install or update any packages using apt or upgrade Ubuntu to 24.04. When I try to run sudo apt upgrade, or install any packages through apt, it gives me the result
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libodbccr2 : Depends: libodbc2 (= 2.3.12-1ubuntu0.23.10.1) but 2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Any attempt to revert libodbc2 to the version that is asked gives the same error message. apt --fix-broken install returns
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  apturl apturl-common blender-data breeze breeze-cursor-theme catdoc fdisk
  fonts-dejavu g++-11 g++-11-multilib gcc-12-base gcc-12-base:i386
  gdal-plugins gdisk genisoimage gir1.2-gweather-3.0
  gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4
  gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gnome-bluetooth-common kaccounts-providers
  kactivities-bin kactivitymanagerd kde-style-breeze kdeconnect kded5
  kdenlive-data keditbookmarks kinit kio kirigami-addons-data
  kpackagelauncherqml kpackagetool5 kpeople-vcard kwin-style-breeze
  lib2geom1.1.0 lib32stdc++-11-dev libabsl20210324 libaccounts-glib0
  libaccounts-qt5-1 libappimage0 libappimage1.0abi1 libarmadillo11
  libatk1.0-data libb2-1 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2
  libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2 libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2
  libblockdev2 libbpf0 libbrotli-dev:i386 libbz2-dev:i386 libc6-dev:i386
  libcamel-1.2-63 libcfitsio10 libclamav9 libcolamd2 libcolord-gtk1
  libcrypt-dev:i386 libcrypto++8 libcupsfilters1 libdazzle-1.0-0
  libdazzle-common libdcmtk16 libdcmtk17 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdmtx0b
  libdns-export1110 libebackend-1.2-10 libebook-1.2-20 libebook-contacts-1.2-3
  libecal-2.0-1 libedata-book-1.2-26 libedata-cal-2.0-1 libedataserver-1.2-26
  libedataserverui-1.2-3 libembree3-3 libepub0 libfakekey0 libflac8
  libflac8:i386 libfontembed1 libfreetype-dev:i386 libgdal33 libgeocode-glib0
  libgeos3.10.2 libglew2.2 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgs9-common libgssdp-1.2-0
  libgupnp-1.2-1 libgupnp-igd-1.0-4 libgweather-3-16 libgweather-common
  libharfbuzz-subset0 libhfstospell11 libhwloc-plugins libhwloc15 libicu70
  libicu70:i386 libisc-export1105 libixml10 libjemalloc2 libkaccounts2
  libkdecorations2-5v5 libkdecorations2private10 libkdecorations2private9
  libkf5activities5 libkf5archive-data libkf5archive5 libkf5attica5
  libkf5auth5 libkf5bluezqt-data libkf5bluezqt6 libkf5bookmarks-data
  libkf5bookmarks5 libkf5calendarevents5 libkf5completion-data
  libkf5completion5 libkf5contacts-data libkf5contacts5 libkf5crash5
  libkf5declarative-data libkf5declarative5 libkf5doctools5
  libkf5filemetadata-bin libkf5filemetadata-data libkf5filemetadata3
  libkf5globalaccel-bin libkf5globalaccel-data libkf5globalaccel5
  libkf5globalaccelprivate5 libkf5i18nlocaledata5 libkf5iconthemes-bin
  libkf5iconthemes-data libkf5iconthemes5 libkf5idletime5 libkf5itemviews-data
  libkf5itemviews5 libkf5jobwidgets-data libkf5jobwidgets5 libkf5kcmutils-data
  libkf5kcmutils5 libkf5kcmutilscore5 libkf5kiocore5 libkf5kiofilewidgets5
  libkf5kiogui5 libkf5kiontlm5 libkf5kiowidgets5 libkf5kirigami2-5
  libkf5modemmanagerqt6 libkf5newstuff-data libkf5newstuff5
  libkf5newstuffcore5 libkf5newstuffwidgets5 libkf5notifyconfig-data
  libkf5notifyconfig5 libkf5package-data libkf5package5 libkf5parts-data
  libkf5parts-plugins libkf5parts5 libkf5people-data libkf5people5
  libkf5peoplebackend5 libkf5peoplewidgets5 libkf5plasma5 libkf5plasmaquick5
  libkf5prison5 libkf5pulseaudioqt3 libkf5purpose-bin libkf5purpose5
  libkf5quickaddons5 libkf5solid5 libkf5solid5-data libkf5sonnet5-data
  libkf5sonnetcore5 libkf5sonnetui5 libkf5style5 libkf5syndication5abi1
  libkf5textwidgets-data libkf5textwidgets5 libkf5xmlgui-bin libkf5xmlgui-data
  libkf5xmlgui5 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.5-0:i386 liblog4cplus-2.0.5
  libmediainfo0v5 libmms0 libmozjs-91-0 libmpdec3 libmujs1
  libnautilus-extension1a libnetpbm10 libnsl-dev:i386 libnsl2:i386 libodbccr2
  libopenal1:i386 libopencolorio1v5 libopencolorio2.1 libopencv-videoio4.5d
  libopenh264-6 libopenshot-audio7 libopenshot19 liborcus-0.17-0
  liborcus-parser-0.17-0 libosdcpu3.5.0 libosdgpu3.5.0 libparted-fs-resize0
  libpcre3 libperl5.34 libplacebo192 libpng-dev:i386 libpng-tools
  libprotobuf-lite23 libpugixml1v5 libpystring0 libpython3.10
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libqmobipocket2 libqpdf28
  libqt5multimediaquick5 libqt5networkauth5 libqt5quickparticles5
  libqt5webengine-data libqt5webengine5 libqt5webenginecore5 libqt6bodymovin6
  libqt6core6 libqt6dbus6 libqt6gui6 libqt6hunspellinputmethod6
  libqt6labsanimation6 libqt6labsfolderlistmodel6 libqt6labsqmlmodels6
  libqt6labssettings6 libqt6labssharedimage6 libqt6labswavefrontmesh6
  libqt6multimedia6 libqt6network6 libqt6opengl6 libqt6qml6 libqt6qmlcore6
  libqt6qmllocalstorage6 libqt6qmlmodels6 libqt6qmlworkerscript6
  libqt6qmlxmllistmodel6 libqt6quick6 libqt6quickcontrols2-6
  libqt6quickcontrols2impl6 libqt6quickdialogs2-6
  libqt6quickdialogs2quickimpl6 libqt6quickdialogs2utils6 libqt6quicklayouts6
  libqt6quickparticles6 libqt6quickshapes6 libqt6quicktemplates2-6
  libqt6quicktimeline6 libqt6quickwidgets6 libqt6sql6 libqt6sql6-sqlite
  libqt6statemachine6 libqt6statemachineqml6 libqt6svg6 libqt6virtualkeyboard6
  libqt6waylandclient6 libqt6waylandcompositor6
  libqt6waylandeglclienthwintegration6
  libqt6waylandeglcompositorhwintegration6 libqt6widgets6
  libqt6wlshellintegration6 libqt6xml6 libraw20 libre2-10 libre2-9
  librest-0.7-0 librygel-core-2.6-2 librygel-db-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-2.6-2
  librygel-server-2.6-2 libsdl-image1.2 libsignon-plugins-common1
  libsignon-qt5-1 libsnapd-glib1 libsndio7.0:i386 libsoup-gnome2.4-1
  libspatialite8 libspnav0 libsquashfuse0 libsquish0 libstdc++-11-dev
  libsuitesparseconfig5 libsuperlu6 libtbbbind-2-5 libtesseract5 libtfm1
  libtiff5:i386 libtinyxml2-9 libtinyxml2.6.2v5 libtirpc-dev:i386
  libtirpc3:i386 libts0 libupnp13 libvncserver1 libvoikko1 libx32stdc++-11-dev
  libxcb-record0 libxdgutilsbasedir1.0.1 libxdgutilsdesktopentry1.0.1
  libxnvctrl0 libxslt1.1:i386 libyaml-cpp0.7 libyaml-cpp0.8 libzen0v5 libzip4
  libzxingcore1 linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-28 linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-35
  linux-libc-dev:i386 mediainfo perl-modules-5.34 plasma-framework
  python3-macaroonbakery python3-protobuf python3-pymacaroons python3-renderpm
  python3-reportlab-accel python3-rfc3339 python3-tz python3.10
  python3.10-minimal qml-module-org-kde-bluezqt qml-module-org-kde-kconfig
  qml-module-org-kde-kirigami-addons-labs-mobileform
  qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols
  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons qml-module-org-kde-newstuff
  qml-module-org-kde-people qml-module-org-kde-prison
  qml-module-org-kde-purpose qml-module-org-kde-qqc2desktopstyle
  qml-module-org-kde-sonnet qml-module-qt-labs-platform
  qml-module-qtmultimedia qml-module-qtquick-particles2 qml-module-qtwebengine
  qml-module-ubuntu-onlineaccounts qml6-module-qt-labs-animation
  qml6-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel qml6-module-qt-labs-lottieqt
  qml6-module-qt-labs-platform qml6-module-qt-labs-qmlmodels
  qml6-module-qt-labs-settings qml6-module-qt-labs-sharedimage
  qml6-module-qt-labs-wavefrontmesh qml6-module-qtcore qml6-module-qtqml
  qml6-module-qtqml-models qml6-module-qtqml-statemachine
  qml6-module-qtqml-workerscript qml6-module-qtqml-xmllistmodel
  qml6-module-qtquick qml6-module-qtquick-controls qml6-module-qtquick-dialogs
  qml6-module-qtquick-layouts qml6-module-qtquick-localstorage
  qml6-module-qtquick-nativestyle qml6-module-qtquick-particles
  qml6-module-qtquick-shapes qml6-module-qtquick-templates
  qml6-module-qtquick-timeline qml6-module-qtquick-tooling
  qml6-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard qml6-module-qtquick-window
  qt6-gtk-platformtheme qt6-qpa-plugins qt6-translations-l10n qt6-wayland
  signon-plugin-oauth2 sonnet-plugins sshfs swh-plugins zlib1g-dev:i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libodbc2 libodbc2:i386
Suggested packages:
  odbc-postgresql tdsodbc odbc-postgresql:i386 tdsodbc:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libodbc2 libodbc2:i386
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 90 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/336 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1024 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-calib3d4.5d:amd64' missing
; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-flann4.5d:amd64' missing; 
assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libopencv-features2d4.5d:amd64' miss
ing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 322299 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libodbc2_2.3.12-1ubuntu0.23.10.1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libodbc2_2.3.12-1ubuntu0.
23.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive syntax
Preparing to unpack .../libodbc2_2.3.12-1ubuntu0.23.10.1_i386.deb ...
De-configuring libodbc2:amd64 (2.3.9-5ubuntu0.1), to allow configuration of libo
dbc2:i386 (2.3.12-1ubuntu0.23.10.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libodbc2_2.3.12-1ubuntu0.
23.10.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 triggers ci file contains unknown directive syntax
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libodbc2_2.3.12-1ubuntu0.23.10.1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libodbc2_2.3.12-1ubuntu0.23.10.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

(sorry this looks so messy, sudo apt autoremove gives me the first error message again!)
I saw a post on the Linux Mint forum that had the same problem, and they suggested I run
sudo ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i libodbc2

which returned
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     253 Mar 31 06:20 libodbc2:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     220 Mar 21 11:18 libodbc2:amd64.md5sums
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      30 Mar 21 11:18 libodbc2:amd64.shlibs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4530 Mar 21 11:18 libodbc2:amd64.symbols
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      72 Mar 21 11:18 libodbc2:amd64.triggers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     247 Mar 31 06:20 libodbc2:i386.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     218 Mar 21 11:18 libodbc2:i386.md5sums
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      30 Mar 21 11:18 libodbc2:i386.shlibs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    4530 Mar 21 11:18 libodbc2:i386.symbols
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      72 Mar 21 11:18 libodbc2:i386.triggers

implying that I have two separate architectures here. I'm not sure whether it's smart to remove them, as apparently worked in the Mint case, but it does seem wrong. They don't have PPA addresses in apt-cache show, so the standard procedure for removing their repositories doesn't seem to work. If I run apt-cache show against libodbc2, it returns the amd64 version, but if I specify it also shows the i386 version. How do I fix this so I can upgrade to the new LTS?
